# Running a background service android without freezing the UI

Tags: android, multithreading, service, background, android-task

I need to log "Some text" in the devices storage after every 5 minutes can some one point me to the best way to do this.
But i do not want the main thread to freeze and the logging thread should be alive all the time.
I tried this but it seems to freeze my emulator
is there a better way to do the same

```
public class DataWriteService extends Service {

private FileIOHelper fileHelper= new FileIOHelper("Test.txt");
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    //Gets location and writes to a file 
    fileHelper.writeToFile(this, "Some text");

    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

Comment: Quoting [the JavaDocs for `Service`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html): "A Service is not a thread" and, in [the JavaDocs for `onStartCommand()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand(android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int)): "Note that the system calls this on your service's main thread... You should always avoid stalling the main thread's event loop. When doing long-running operations, network calls, or heavy disk I/O, you should kick off a new thread". You have not started a thread, so your work is freezing your UI.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Handler` or seperate background thread to finish your long work. once you are done,post the value on UI thread.

Btw, on Android O +, the service would only run as long as your app is alive. As soon as your app goes in background, the app will shut down the service. Consider using JobScheduler